# Service discovery for a fixed period of time when using NsdManager.DiscoveryListener

Tags: android, multithreading, service-discovery

I am attempting to implement a class for service discovery using Android's NsdManager API. I am wondering how one could start the service search for a fixed amount of time from the main activity, then stop it to use the results of the search?

The [NsdManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/nsd/NsdManager.html) API says the call should be asynchronous

> The API is asynchronous and responses to requests from an application
>   are on listener callbacks on a seperate thread.

I have successfully sent the class a handler which updates my UI thread with the message response but I'm not sure how I can then stop the discovery service after, say, 5 seconds without blocking the Main Thread with a timer :S

I hope it is a relevant question and I have provided enough information.

Br

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use a timer, just use [postDelayed(Runnable r, long millis)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) on your View. You can call that from any thread, so you could call it from the callback.